# Сделать первую букву большой в строке

Tags: c#

Есть строка `САНКТ-ПЕТЕРБУРГ`, как мне привести ее в строку `Санкт-Петербург`?
Сплитить строку, переводить весь текст в нижний регистр, потом увеличивать первую букву, потом соединять не есть хорошо. Мб есть более красивое решение?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Попробуйте метод [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
```

Пример: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T9PZxw).

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Grundy Если это мне, то я не понял, что вы хотели сказать.

Comment: это в дополнение к ответу ссылка на справку по функции которая в нем используется :)

Comment: @Grundy Ссылку я добавил, спасибо.

Comment: @DmitryD. да, прошу прощения. Удалил комментарий.